# mysql utf8 issues with french character

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation, mysql-5.6, utf8mb4

Trying to insert a simple 'é' into a table on mysql (v 5.6) terminal windows server 2008, I get Incorrect string value: '\x82' for column 'colum_name'

I've been searching on stack overflow for a day now. I think I am going crazy. All my collations are utf8mb4:

```
/*column*/
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM table_name;
utf8mb4_unicode_ci

/*database*/
show variables like "character_set_database";
utf8mb4

/*table*/
SHOW TABLE STATUS where name like 'table_name';
utf8mb4_unicode_ci

/*variables*/
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

Here's what I added to my my.ini

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4 

[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
character-set-server = utf8mb4
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
```

I am stuck

Comment: you might want to tag your post with the plan 'mysql' tag, or it's not going to get a lot of attention.

Comment: @antiduh -- I would not have seen this if it hand not been for the other tags.  I avoid just `mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

> I get Incorrect string value: '\x82' for column 'colum_name'

Please explain.  Show us the query.  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

x82, in the popular latin1 character set is a variant of comma:  `‚`.  It is unrelated to e-acute (HEX: latin1: E9, utf8: C3A9).